# Сохранение файла во внутреннюю память Android

Tags: java, android

Как сохранять файлы из приложения во внешнюю память понятно - getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). Но как сохранить файл во внутреннюю память? Если нет sd карты.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень просто гуглится. Либо задан некорректно и я не понял что хочет автор на самом деле. Метод сохранения одинаковый. Разница только в указываемом пути файла.

Путь получаете таким образом. Если у вас нет sd карты, то он уж точно не вернет на нее ссылку

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

> Для создания файла в одной из этих директорий можно использовать
>   конструктор File(), который передает элемент File, предоставляемый
>   одним из вышеприведенных методов, с помощью которого указывается
>   директория во внутренней памяти. Например:

```
File file = new File(путь файла, filename);
```

Кроме того, можно вызвать метод openFileOutput() для получения объекта FileOutputStream , производящего запись в файл во внутренней памяти. Вот пример записи текста в файл:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```